# Connecting two machines via internet using WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have recently started studying WCF. So I written a simple application. Client sends a string and server just outputs it on the screen. The app works fine on my computer with local address. But when i try to connect with my IP through internet, i get this exception:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://(IP):4000/IContract that could accept the message.

Port is open and available. Please tell me, what I am missing. here is how I declare address:
`Uri adress = new Uri("http://(IP of computer, running server):4000/IContract");`
I`ve taken my IP address from a website. It gave me two of the. My Ip address and my local IP address. So, local works only when client and server both on my PC. When I try not local - nothing works at all.
Would appreciate any help.

Here is the code from Service provider:

```
    Uri adress = new Uri("http://212.3.115.3:4000/IContract");
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    Type contract = typeof(IContract);

    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(contract,binding,adress);
    host.Open();
```

Here is the code from Service consumer:

```
        Uri adress = new Uri("http://212.3.115.3:4000/IContract");
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(adress);

        ChannelFactory<IContract> factory = new ChannelFactory<IContract>(binding, endpoint);
        IContract channel = factory.CreateChannel();
        channel.Say(tmp);
```

Comment: you requre a static ip on the remote machine which you wont to connect

Comment: write somthing about your wcf service codes in the qestion so anyone can help you

Comment: Your machine may well be behind a router, for this to work you'll need to configure the router to forward traffic on port 4000 to your machine.

Comment: @LoekD I thought about that, so I plugged Ethernet cable directly into my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordered static IP for the machine, containing Service Provider. And plugged Ethernet cable directly into PC. It worked, so thanks, everybody.